# Error when finding records with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, find, php

I'm learning about CakePHP, with some videotutorials which are made with CakePHP 1.x. I'm using CakePHP 2.2.2 stable which is the latest version, and when I try to implement the edit function, I'm having this error:

> Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line
>   2666]

This is the code of edit function:

```
function edit($id = null){
            if(!$id){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Tarea invalida');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
            }
            if(empty($this->data)){
                $this->data = $this->Tarea->find(array('id'=>$id));
            }else{
                if($this->Tarea->save($this->data)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash('La tarea ha sido salvada');
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('La tarea no ha podido ser salvada. Intentelo de nuevo');
                }
            }
        }
```

And I changed

```
$this->data = $this->Tarea->find(array('id'=>$id));
```

to

```
$this->data = $this->Tarea->find('all',array('conditions',array('id'=>$id)));
```

and the error doesn't appear but no data is being retrieved of database...
if I implement:

```
$this->data = his->Tarea->find('first',array('conditions',array('id'=>$id)));
```

the first value always is being retrieved.

Hope your help, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part of your `find` statements is wrong: `array('conditions',array('id'=>$id))`. It has to be: `array('conditions' => array('id'=>$id))`.

Comment: Hi, I solved it, this is what I just implemented: $this->data = $this->Tarea->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));       I had it with all instead of first....changind to first, now it works